# How to draw many 3d objects in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

There are many 3D objects(1000+) constructed by triangles and i need to draw it using Android NDK and OpenGL ES 2.0. Each triangle have vertex coordinates, colors, texture and texture coordinates . I have 2 problems:

1. Function `texture2D(u_Texture,v_TexCoord)` in my fragment shader returns `vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` for each triangle.
2. Low rateframe.

Here is my code:

Loading bmp file and creating texture:

```
void CreateTexture(unsigned &texture, const char * fileName)
{
    char *pFolderName = NULL;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    unsigned char *data = NULL;
    char *pExtension = NULL;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    //check extension
    pExtension = new char[5];
    pExtension[4] = '\0';
    int j = strlen(fileName) - 1;
    do {
        j--;
    } while (j > 0 && fileName[j] != '.');

    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
        j++;
        pExtension[k] = fileName[j];
    }
    if (   0 == strcmp(pExtension, BMP_EXT)
        || 0 == strcmp(pExtension, BMP_EXT1))
    {
        FILE *f = fopen(fileName, "r");
        if(f == NULL) LOGE("Couldn't open texture file %s", fileName);
        fseek(f, 18, SEEK_SET);
        fread(&width, 4, 1, f);
        fread(&height, 4, 1, f);
        data = new unsigned char[width*height*3];
        fseek(f, 54, SEEK_SET);
        fread(data, width*height*3, 1, f);

        char tmp;
        //convert BGR->RGB
        for(int i=0;i<width*height*3-2;i+=3)
        {
            tmp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[i+2];
            data[i+2] = tmp;
        }
        unsigned char *reverseData = new unsigned char[width*height*3];
        for(int j1 = 0; j1 < height; ++j1)
        for(int i1 = 0; i1 < width*3; ++i1)
            reverseData[j1*(width*3)+i1] = data[(height-j1-1)*width*3+i1];
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, reverseData);
        delete []data;
        delete []pExtension;
        delete []reverseData;
    }
}
```

Draw function:

```
void Display(VisObject *obj)
{
    GLint pos = shader.GetAttribLocation("a_Position");
    GLint texpos = shader.GetAttribLocation("a_TexCoord");
    GLint a_color = shader.GetAttribLocation("a_Color");
    GLint texture  = shader.GetUniformLocation("u_Texture");
    GLint textureFlag  = shader.GetUniformLocation("u_TextureFlag");
    for(int i=0; i < obj->CountTr ; i++)
    {
        if (!obj->m_visible) return;

        float color[12];
        if(obj->triangles[i].color[0] < 0)
        {
            color[0] = 1.0f; color[1] = 1.0f; color[2] = 1.0f;color[3] = obj->m_vis_koef;
            color[4] = 1.0f; color[5] = 1.0f; color[6] = 1.0f;color[7] = obj->m_vis_koef;
            color[8] = 1.0f; color[9] = 1.0f; color[10] = 1.0f;color[11] = obj->m_vis_koef;
        }
        else
        {
            color[0]  = obj->triangles[i].color[0]; color[1]  = obj->triangles[i].color[1];
            color[2]  = obj->triangles[i].color[2]; color[3]  = obj->triangles[i].color[3];

            color[4]  = obj->triangles[i].color[0]; color[5]  = obj->triangles[i].color[1];
            color[6]  = obj->triangles[i].color[2]; color[7]  = obj->triangles[i].color[3];

            color[8]  = obj->triangles[i].color[0]; color[9]  = obj->triangles[i].color[1];
            color[10] = obj->triangles[i].color[2]; color[11] = obj->triangles[i].color[3];
        }
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        if(obj->m_num_texture > 0)
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,g_Texture[obj->m_num_texture] );
        else
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, obj->triangles[i].numtex );
        shader.Uniform1i(texture, 0);
        float vertices[] = {
                obj->triangles[i].verts[0].x, obj->triangles[i].verts[0].y, obj->triangles[i].verts[0].z,
                obj->triangles[i].verts[1].x, obj->triangles[i].verts[1].y, obj->triangles[i].verts[1].z,
                obj->triangles[i].verts[2].x, obj->triangles[i].verts[2].y, obj->triangles[i].verts[2].z
        };
        float texcoords[] = {
                obj->triangles[i].tex[0].U, obj->triangles[i].tex[0].V,
                obj->triangles[i].tex[1].U, obj->triangles[i].tex[1].V,
                obj->triangles[i].tex[2].U, obj->triangles[i].tex[2].V
        };
        glVertexAttribPointer(pos, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
        checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos);
        checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
        glVertexAttribPointer(texpos, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, texcoords);
        checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(texpos);
        checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
        shader.Uniform1f(textureFlag, 1.0f);
        glVertexAttribPointer(a_color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, color);
        checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(a_color);
        checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
attribute vec3 a_Position;
attribute vec2 a_TexCoord;
attribute vec4 a_Color;

varying vec2 v_TexCoord;
varying vec4 v_Color;

uniform mat4 u_projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 u_modelviewMatrix;

void main(void) 
{
    mat4 mvpMatrix = u_projectionMatrix*u_modelviewMatrix;
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix*vec4(a_Position, 1.0);
    v_TexCoord = a_TexCoord;
    v_Color = a_Color;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 v_TexCoord;
varying vec4 v_Color;
uniform sampler2D u_Texture;
uniform float u_TextureFlag;

void main(void) 
{
    gl_FragColor = u_TextureFlag*texture2D(u_Texture,v_TexCoord)*v_Color + (1.0 - u_TextureFlag)*v_Color;
}
```

I've tried to declare vertex array and other as `float vertices[3*3*obj->CountTr];` and in cycle just set the values of array. After cycle i draw triangles: 
`glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3*obj->CountTr);` 
It works much faster, but i dont understand how to set different textures for triangles if it necessary.

Comment: The line shader.Uniform1f(textureFlag, 1.0f); seems to set the texture uniform which must correspond to the desired active texture which seems to be 0, not 1. Try this to begin with.

Comment: first test v_Color if it is ok, gl_FragColor = vec4(v_Color.x, v_Color.y, 0.0, 1.0); 
then test the value of u_Texture (must be 0)
if it is still black, then there's something wrong with the texture2d

Comment: @MaticOblak i think textureFlag is used for as blending factor, "texture" is the active texture.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. Well there are many things that can go wrong so that your texture is not visible. You say that you always get the black pixel from the texture in the fragment shader so try pinpointing the issue as far as possible. Modify the the fragment shader so it always displays the middle pixel in the texture by using vec2(.5, .5) instead of the texture coordinates (I hope your texture is not black in the middle). As for the performance you should try do draw as many triangles in a single draw call as possible so start thinking about restructuring the drawing part.

Comment: I've found the reason of black textures. There was array of texture names defined in header file as static GLuint g_Texture[MAX_TEXTURES]. I move it to .cpp file, then define it with "extern" modifier in other file (with render function). So this solve one problem.

Comment: @MaticOblak so to improve the performance i should divide triangles(from all objects) into groups with the same texture unit and  then draw each group. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, at least. Another thing is creating a texture atlas where you would join multiple textures into a single one (put multiple images onto the same texture) and restructure the texture coordinates to include the data offset on the texture buffer. This way you will decrease the texture count, decrease the texture binding calls and be able to draw the whole scene in minimum number of draw calls which is a huge performance gain. Be carful of the maximum texture size which depends on the GPU though.